# Getting a certain number of results from a related table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I have a posts and a comments table:

```
Post (id, title)
Comment(id, postid, comment, commentdate)
```

I am trying to select the latest 10 posts which were commented with the comment dates. What is the query for getting this?

Example:

If I was trying to get latest 3 posts:

```
Post
---
1 P1
2 P2
3 P3
4 P4

Comment
---
1 1 C1 01:01
2 3 C2 01:02
3 3 C3 01:03
4 2 C4 01:04
5 2 C5 01:05
6 1 C6 01:06
7 4 C7 01:07
8 4 C8 01:08

Exptected result:
---

4 P4 01:08
1 P1 01:06
2 P2 01:05
```

Searching Comment table from last record, in the postid column, I find 4, 1 and 2 respectively (and distinctively). I find 3 comments and I stop there.

Comment: Why is post 3 not in the expected result? Also, can you please tell us what version of SQL Server you're using? The [tag:related] tag is pretty useless, but [tag:SQL-Server-2005] would be, for example.

Comment: post 3 is not in the result because the latest commented 3 posts are P4, P1 (it was commented just before P4) and P2 (it was commented just before P1).

Comment: Then can you please clarify whether you want the top 3 or the top 10? Your question asks for both in different spots.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest surefire approach is something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10
       id,
       title,
       (SELECT MAX(commentdate)
          FROM comment
         WHERE postid = post.id
       ) AS commentdate
  FROM post
 ORDER BY commentdate DESC
;
```

but I wouldn't expect it to perform very well. (It finds, for every post, the most recent comment, and then it uses that to find the ten posts whose most recent comments are the most recent.)

A way that would perform much better, but at the risk of potentially including fewer than ten results in some cases, would be something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10
       id,
       title,
       (SELECT MAX(commentdate)
          FROM comment
         WHERE postid = post.id
       ) AS commentdate
  FROM post
 WHERE id IN
        ( SELECT TOP 100
                 postid
            FROM comment
           ORDER BY commentdate DESC
        )
 ORDER BY commentdate DESC
;
```

which finds the posts that the 100 most recent comments belong to — a maximum of 100 posts — and then applies the above approach to just those posts. (The reason it might return fewer than ten posts is that the 100 most recent comments might all belong to just nine posts — or just five posts, or just one post.)

*(Disclaimer: I have not tested either of the above queries.)*

Comment: The syntax is not correct (both queries are missing a `FROM`) and I think you meant top 3, not top 10.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I've added the missing `FROM post`, thanks. And no, I meant top 10: that's what the OP specified: "I am trying to select the latest 10 posts which were commented with the comment dates." You were probably confused by the example that followed: "**If** I was trying to get latest 3 posts: [...]" (emphasis mine).

Comment: I agree there's some confusion in the question, but if he wanted top 3, wouldn't post 3 be in the expected result? I asked for confirmation on this already and he didn't want post 3 to show up, since it's not in the top 3. See also "I find 3 comments and I stop there."

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I don't think there's any confusion in the question. The question explains that the actual desired query is to get the *ten* most recent posts; but the example results are just *three*, because that's easier to show. Like how if I was asking about a program to print the first 1,000 primes, I might show sample output with just the first ten primes, with an explanatory note exactly like the OP's. (The "I find 3 comments and I stop there" is part of that example, so naturally it's about top-3 rather than top-10.)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT      TOP 3 Post.postId
            , Post.post
            , latestComment.leftAt
FROM        Post
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT      postId
                            , MAX(leftAt) AS leftAt
                FROM        Comment
                GROUP BY    postId
            ) AS latestComment
              ON    Post.postId = latestComment.postId
ORDER BY    latestComment.leftAt DESC
            , Post.postId
```

Working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86b19/8)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @n INT = 3; -- or 10, or whatever

;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT
        postid, commentdate,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY commentdate DESC)
      FROM dbo.comment AS c
), y AS 
(
  SELECT postid, rn = MIN(rn) FROM x
  GROUP BY postid
)
SELECT TOP (@n) p.postid, p.title, x.commentdate
FROM x INNER JOIN y ON x.rn = y.rn
INNER JOIN dbo.post AS p ON p.postid = x.postid
ORDER BY x.commentdate DESC;
```

Or slightly simpler:

```
DECLARE @n INT = 3; -- or 10, or whatever

;WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT TOP (@n) postid, t = MAX(commentdate)
    FROM dbo.comment
    GROUP BY postid ORDER BY t DESC
)
SELECT p.postid, p.title, commentdate = x.t 
FROM x INNER JOIN dbo.post AS p ON x.postid = p.postid
ORDER BY x.t DESC;
```